# Is lactic acid build up the cause of muscle fatigue or only a symptom?

Tags: molecular-biology, exercise

If your body could magically instantly remove lactic acid as it is produced, would that make you immune to muscle fatigue, or is the lactic acid only a symptom of muscle fatigue and instead exists, at least partially, as a means for your body to measure the stress your muscles are under to keep you from overexerting and damaging yourself? Would your body still have other kinds of immediate and daily maintenance to do to deal with muscle fatigue even if lactic acid wasn't a limiting factor?

Comment: Always wondered this.

Comment: Accumulation of any biomolecules in any condition can't be a symptom. A symptom is defined as a physical or mental feeling that a person experiences, which can be an indication of disease. Symptoms can be headache, nausea, cough, running nose, change in body temperature and they never show up on the diagnostic tests. So, the accumulation of lactic acid can never be a symptom. However, lactic acid is one of the cause of muscle fatigue indirectly.

Comment: As a biochemist I know how lactic acid is normally handled in the body and how it might affect muscle function in circumstances that perhaps did not arise frequently in early man. What I do not know is the medical status of what you refer to as “muscle fatigue”. I doubt very much your ideas about it being a sensor, and wonder whether you are familiar with what is known as the Cori Cycle. However I do not know. Given the lack of response I wonder whether you would be better to migrate your question to SE Medical Sciences, where someone might know about muscle fatigue.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

- Removal of lactic acid would only solve the [lactic acidosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactic_acidosis) problem.
- Conversion of glucose to lactic acid $\ce{(C6H12O6 \to 2 C3H6O3)}$ only produces **two** ATP per glucose molecule. You will still miss **up to 34 ATP** omitting the [oxidative phosphorylation](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Microbiology/Microbiology_(Kaiser)/Unit_7%3A_Microbial_Genetics_and_Microbial_Metabolism/18%3A_Microbial_Metabolism/18.3%3A_Aerobic_Respiration/18.3E%3A_Theoretical_ATP_Yield) step.
- Once the free glucose in your cell is exhausted, you will then have to rely on [glycogenolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycogenolysis) which is rate-limited by [glycogen phosphorylase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycogen_phosphorylase).
- As your glycogen gets depleted, you will have to [import glucose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLUT4) (as well as fatty acids and certain amino acids) from the blood for sustained energy production.